# JQuery success results in \r\n characters

Tags: php, jquery

I have these characters in my results.
The same code works fine on another page.

This is my PHP:

// Insert Data
    $queryData = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_Category (`Status`, `Parent`, `Name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

```
$insertData = $queryData->execute (
    array (
        $Status,
        $Parent,
        $Name,
    )
);

if(insertData) { echo "success"; } else { echo "error"; }
```

This is my JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"ajax/Category.php?ajaxPost=newCategory",
    data:$('form#frmAction').serialize(),
    success: function(result){
        if(result == "success")
        {
            alert("ok ");
        }
        else if(result == "error")
        {

        alert("püff");
        }
    }
});
```

[This is what the Firefox Debugger shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wFPj.png)

And my result is:

```
result = "success\r\n"
```

Comment: Please show us all the code from the PHP script `ajax/Category.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\r\n` refer to the end of the string characters. Interacting between JavaScript and PHP using ajax is usually implemented using [json](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp), which is a data format supported widely by all programming languages.

You may refactor your code as follows. The `die()` function is used to ensure no extra output is printed by the PHP script, since this would result in invalid json syntax.

**category.php**

```
if($insertData) { 
    die(json_encode(['result' => true])); 
} else { 
    die(json_encode(['result' => false, 'errorMessage' => 'Optional error message goes here.'])); 
}
```

**jQuery**

Note: I have used the `$.post()` function, this is a shorthand for `$.ajax(type: 'POST')`.

```
$.post('ajax/Category.php?ajaxPost=newCategory', $('form#frmAction').serialize(), function(r) {
    if(r.result) {
        alert("OK");
    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong: " + r.errorMessage);
    }
}, 'json');
```

Comment: dataType: json, broke editor. not receiving form data

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove unwanted \r\n:

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

```js
var result = "success\r\n".trim();
if (result == "success")
    console.log("ok ");
else
    console.log("not ok ");
```